# Use GtkSourceView with Rust

Tags: rust, gtk

I want to use GtkSourceView in my Rust app.

I've created the UI file using Glade. I had to install the component and link it.

This is my Rust code:

```
use gtk::prelude::*;


fn main() {
    if gtk::init().is_err() {
        println!("Failed to initialize GTK.");
        return;
    }
    let glade_src = include_str!("user_interface.glade");
    let builder = gtk::Builder::new_from_string(glade_src);    
    let window: gtk::Window = builder.get_object("main_window").unwrap();

    window.show_all();

    gtk::main();
}
```

...and the error I'm getting when I try `cargo run`:

```
alex@smartalex-bed:~/.repos/codelib/rust/venom$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.05s
     Running `target/debug/venom`

(venom:10028): Gtk-ERROR **: 04:25:30.689: failed to add UI: .:17:1 Invalid object type 'GtkSourceView'
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I found [this](https://lib.rs/crates/sourceview) and tried to include it in my Cargo.toml, however the error persists.

How can I use GtkSourceView in my Rust app?

This is `user_interface.glade`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <requires lib="gtksourceview" version="4.0"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="main_window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child type="titlebar">
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkSourceView">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="left_margin">2</property>
            <property name="right_margin">2</property>
            <property name="monospace">True</property>
            <property name="show_line_numbers">True</property>
            <property name="show_line_marks">True</property>
            <property name="tab_width">4</property>
            <property name="auto_indent">True</property>
            <property name="insert_spaces_instead_of_tabs">True</property>
            <property name="show_right_margin">True</property>
            <property name="highlight_current_line">True</property>
            <property name="smart_backspace">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: AFAIK, UI builders use dynamic linking magic to access widgets from a library. But rust will not link the library unless it sees a referenced symbol in your code. Can you try adding this line just after calling `gtk_init()`: `unsafe { gtk_source_sys::gtk_source_view_get_type() };` to force the reference? Don't forget to add the crate `gtk-source-sys` to your `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: The safe wrapper of the above would be just `sourceview::View::static_type();`

Answer (score 3):

I was able to run the program by adding following line:

```rust
sourceview::View::static_type();
```

The full example code:

```rust
use gtk::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    if gtk::init().is_err() {
        println!("Failed to initialize GTK.");
        return;
    }

    sourceview::View::static_type();

    let glade_src = include_str!("user_interface.glade");
    let builder = gtk::Builder::new_from_string(glade_src);
    let window: gtk::Window = builder.get_object("main_window").unwrap();

    window.show_all();

    gtk::main();
}
```

Further, `Cargo.toml` contains following dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
gtk = { version = "*", features = ["v3_22"] }
sourceview = "*"
```